# SQL PHP get last ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very basic web service (PHP) that inserts data into two tables.

Very nice and simple script

```
$conn = new MySQLi($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "INSERT INTO db (NAME) VALUES ('$Name')";
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

The next table insert is pretty much as simple however uses an auto incrementing ID from the above table/insert.

If i use $conn->insert_id what would happen if i had two threads use this script and both do an insert before i call insert_id?

Thanks

Comment: why dont you try it and tell us?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php):

> The mysqli_insert_id() function returns the ID generated by a query (usually INSERT) on a table with a column having the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute. If no INSERT or UPDATE statements were sent via **this connection**, or if the modified table does not have a column with the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute, this function will return zero.

Emphasis mine.

In other words, the function `mysqli_insert_id` returns the ID inserted with the current connection. PHP is not "threaded", which means that every request is completed and killed before a new one is started (somewhat simplified, but you can think of it this way). This, along with the implementation of the function, guarantees that you will get the correct ID returned.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid conflict you can do the query below before inserting :

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT your_incremented_id FROM db ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1";

$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$id_result=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

//get the last inserted row id


$id=$id_result['your_incremented_id']+1;

$time=rand(0,0.2);
sleep($time);
// your insert query with the new id

?>
```

that should avoid your problem